# The native debug symbols contain an invalid directory symbols. Only Android ABIs are supported

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-console

When i'm trying to upload my symbols.zip file on play console this error msg is coming please help me about this "The native debug symbols contain an invalid directory symbols. Only Android ABIs are supported" - unity

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58G7T.jpg)

Comment: What are the directories in the zip file?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5):

By default the debug symbols zip that Unity produces does not conform to what Google Play expect. However its easily rectified as long as you follow these steps accurately.

---

**Step 1: Make A Back Up**

Before proceeding make a back up of the original symbols.zip file! You want to keep this around in case you need it in the future. Though in practice I've never found a need for it but its better to be safe. I usually unzip it then use 7-Zip to re-compress it to a much smaller filer.

---

**Step 2: Unzip the Symbols and Fix Them**

Unzip the symbols.zip to a separate folder.

Within it you should find one or two folders called 'arm64-v8a' and/or 'armeabi-v7a' depending on if you are supporting older 32bit arm cpus.

For each of those folders;

- Open the folder.
- Delete the file 'libil2cpp.so.debug'.
- Rename the file 'libil2cpp.sym' to 'libil2cpp.so'.

Sometimes the file names are different, in that case

- Delete the file 'libil2cpp.dbg.so'
- Rename the file 'libil2cpp.sym.so' to 'libil2cpp.so'
- Rename the file 'libunity.sym.so' to 'libunity.so'

---

**Step 3: Zip Up Your New Symbols**

Select the folders and zip them up.

On Windows you can simply use right-click - send to - compressed ( zipped ) folder, though I use 7-Zip via 'add to archive' using the zip format with a high compression level.

**IMPORTANT**
You must ensure that the zip directory structure matches that of the original Unity generated symbols.zip. Which is that both folders are 'loose' in the zip file, they are NOT children of a parent folder!

For example instead of having a zip of

*MyApp-1.0.2-v2.symbols / arm64-v8a / libil2cpp.sym.so*

you might end up with

*MyApp-1.0.2-v2.symbols/MyApp-1.0.2-v2.symbols / arm64-v8a / libil2cpp.sym.so*

---

**Step 4: Rename Your Newly Zipped File**

Rename the newly zipped file to match the name of the original Unity generated symbols.zip file.

---

**Step 5: Upload Your New Symbols.zip**

You should be able to upload the symbols.zip to the Play Console without error.

If you do get an error, double check the zip against the original one from Unity. Make sure the filenames match exactly and ensure the directory structures match!

*If you still have an error you may need to rename 'libunity.sym.so' to 'libunity.so' in both folders too - though there are conflicting reports on that and I've never had to.*

---

It should be noted that Unity's default compression settings for the zip are poor, generating very large files with poor compression. When you re-zip the symbols after following the steps above it should be much smaller. For example I frequently get 1GB debug.symbol.zips from Unity, but end up with only about 150MB zip file after performing the steps above.

Comment: i tried these 10 times, its not working.. please help me out the error came, but its different problem.

Comment: You are going to need to provide more details. Be specific saying its'not working' doesn't help. Does you symbol.zip contain the files I've outline or is it different? What version of Unity are you using.

Comment: Unity hub : Version 3.0.0-beta.7 (3.0.0-beta.7)
Unity : Versio 2020.3.21f1 personal
and yes i have tried these all with step by step but the issue was not fixed

Comment: I'm sorry I don't think i'm able to help without more details and StackOverflow simply isn't set up to allow the back and forth needed to try and 'debug' the issue you are having. I would suggest at this stage you switch over to making a post on the Unity forum and see if anyone there has run into the issue you are having.

Comment: I am generating debug symbols zip with Unity editor 2020.3  LTS version. But this version generates a 1.3 GB debug symbols file, so it can not be uploaded to GP unfortunately. So, I extract this zip file, after deleting the mentioned files and renaming operations, I select 'arm64-v8a' and 'armeabi-v7a' folders and zip them instead of the parent folder, which is the key point. Hope it helps the readers.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me (**Unity 2020.3.3f1**) was the following:

1. Unzip symbols
2. Rename *libunity.sym.so* to *libunity.so* in both folders (*arm64-v8a* and *armeabi-v7a*)
3. Now both folders contain the following files:

- *libil2cpp.dbg.so*
- *libil2cpp.sym.so*
- *libunity.so*

4. Zip everything in a way that preserves the original file structure and use the same name as before unzipping
5. Upload

For the renaming I used the bash file provided in [this post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/play-console-error-the-native-debug-symbols-contain-an-unexpected-file.981867/#post-7056169).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend zipping the armeabi-v7a folder and armeabi-v8a folder instead of zipping their parent folder "symbols". This would not give the above error.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it.

I uploaded only the armeabi-v7a folder.

Please try again.

filename : libil2cpp.so, libunity.so

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).